# Getting images from server for @2x and @3x

Tags: ios, iphone, image-size

Lets say that I have an imageView sized with Auto-layout to full width of the screen (which means that the width will be different for iPhone5, iPhone 6 and 6 Plus) and a ratio of 0.5 for the height. The image for this imageView is fetched from a server.

What is the correct way to set the image size for each display (I can store different images for each device, I just can not figure out the correct sizes.

Any explanation ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add a parameter to your URL to hint the server which version you need.

```
https://myserver.tld/path/image.png?scale=3
```

In your server, before serving the content, to the client, will parse this parameter and serve accordingly.

An arguably even better approach is to have the required width, height and scale as parameters, and let the server return an image that best fits. This is a more advanced approach, and does not always provide the best results, where manual tweaking may be required.